# How to solve sql server remote exe connection issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Sql server is installed in remote machine. When i connect that remote sql sever 2005 through code or run exe from my system, its working fine.Exe's are placed in remote machine and the sql sever also exists in that machine. When i try to open that exe from that remote system, i am getting sql server connection error.

The exe worked in windows xp without any issue, facing this issue only in windows 7.

Read an article in microsoft, it asks to add new rule under windows firefall, inbounds and outbounds. Added TPC, UDP port as mentioned.

Tried the below 2 links. Still i am in trouble.

http://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/58817-remote-access-sql-server-express-2008-windows-7-a.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181.aspx

Can anybody guide me in this regards.

Comment: You question body says SQL 2005 and question tag is SQL 2008. Which one is it?

Comment: Is the other machine in different domain?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the default SQL Server instance or have you given it a name? If you have named it, you should access it as ServerName\InstanceName

Is it using port 1433? If so, you must open TCP port 1433 in the firewall. If it is not the default instance it is possibly using dynamic ports which may not be open in your firewall. Also you may need to open the UDP port 1434 so the Browser Service can be accessed (essential if you are using dynamic ports).

Is TCP enabled or are you using the default Shared Memory (you said this worked fine from an XP client so I imagine this is OK).